# How to fix Firefox Android faux-bold and faux-italic fonts

Tags: android, css, firefox, fonts

I recently installed Firefox for Android on my phone (Moto G4 Plus running Android 6), and immediately noticed that the fonts look wrong on most websites. Comparing Chrome and Firefox on the same phone, on Firefox sites like Google, Reddit, among others, all show a faux-bold, faux-italic font.

I searched on the web but everything that I have seen is that the sites made a mistake on not import all the faces, but all the fixes are done on the website end.

Since this affects a lot of them, is it possible to fix on my end? Maybe using Stylish or another add-on? Checking `about:config` I didn't see anything I could use. And firefox is using "Clear Sans" as default font.

Comment: 12-02-2018 still an ugly font on installing Firefox for the first time